# Wordpress: post thumbnails/post image attachment

Tags: thumbnails

I want to show thumbnails next to my posts in archive page, however it only shows thumbnails if the posts has a featured image.

Is there anyway to make the attached image of the post a thumbnail and show it in the archive page?

At the moment i am using the following code to show thumbnails if set as featured.

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
   <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" >
   <?php the_post_thumbnail(thumbnail, array('class' => 'alignleft')); ?>
   </a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Here is the website http://n1bar.com/category/blog As you can see the first post has an attached image but is not being displayed as thumbnail in the archive page.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

the following code can give you all the images attachments from a post.
put it inside the big while loop.
if you just want to show 1 image, you can modify the code below, cuz i am not sure which image you want to show if there are more than 1 image attachments.

```
    <div class="allthumbs cf">
    <?php

        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'attachment',
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'post_status' => null,
            'post_parent' => $post->ID,
            'order' => 'ASC',

        );

        $attachments = get_posts( $args );
        if ( $attachments ) {
            foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
                $full_img_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment->ID, 'full' );
                echo '<div class="imageWrapper zoom-able"><a href="' . $full_img_url[0] .'">' 
                    .wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'medium' ) . "</a></div>";
            }
        }       
    ?>
    </div>
```